# Windows Service that depends on another absent service

Tags: services

What happens to a Windows service if we delete other services that it depends on? Or, add a dependency to a service name that doesn't exist.

Is it even possible?

What if the service is already running?

Answer (score 0):

I ever did it when I tried to handle a virus in my computer, I must end process some services windows file to get the virus main source. I deleted notepad, msvbvm60.dll and -50.dll. For default windows programs, those usually have no UAC Virtualization that are run by USERINIT.exe or SYSTEM. That means that you can stop it whenever you like and would not disturb the system.

[image]

If it is under UAC of course, some other program related to it will stop too.
On the other hand, the file depends on other file in windows service which is run by User Permission.

If you delete one of the file, of course, it would not work again even if you add a new one.
One file can contain ocx or dll which is built in separated process and become another file.

Virus usually accesses the userinit to run from it by asking permission to act as windows file service which is built by itself and if that is related to other default windows file service, such as kernel32.dll, then you can delete it by remove UAC permission, stop it and delete it.